# Result from database function query to Gorm field

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

In Grails/Groovy, I have defined database fields in Model, I'm using `MyModel.createCriteria().list(...)` to get query result - works fine!

But in addition to fields, I need value from database function. SQL analog would be:

`SELECT foo, bar, calculate_stuff(foo) FROM baz;`

Can I include result from DB function call to Domain as transient value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to accomplish this using the `formula` of the `mapping` for this property. This is known as a derived property. You can read more about it in the [documentation](http://gorm.grails.org/6.1.x/hibernate/manual/#derivedProperties).

For example:

```
class Baz {
  String foo
  String bar
  Long thing

  mapping {
    thing formula: "calculate_stuff(foo)"
  }

}
```

Comment: Excellent - exactly, what I was looking for! Thanks!